# Homonymous synonymic phrases

Tags: phrases, terminology

By the definition that:

*A homonym is a word or phrase that sounds the same as another*
*A synonym is a word or phrase that means the same or similar to another*

A possible example of homonymous synonymic phrases may be:

*"An ice-cold drink"*

and

*"A nice, cold drink"*

My questions are:

1) Is there a proper name for these

2) Are there any other examples of these

3) If there are other examples can either a) You provide a list or b) You provide a place where I  can find more

Thanks :)

Comment: Reminds me of an example in French, with a twist - no synonym. _Cette année-là_ is the name of a song that was performed by Claude François. Loosely translated, it means "Oh, what a year", or "Wow, what a year". An exact homonym that gets thrown around is _Cet âne est là_, which means, "That ass is there". (Yes, _âne_ can also mean "donkey", but it's not as much fun.)

Comment: 'An ice-cold drink' and 'a nice, cold drink' are (barring quibbles about length of pause) homonyms, homonymous phrases, but not homonymous synonymous phrases. Your estimation of the 'almost' involved here is a long way off that intended. Think 'task' and 'job', often interchangeable with no / negligible change in meaning.